# Inheritance behaviour of non-virtual methods in CIL

Tags: .net, cil

In CIL, what is the behaviour of a virtual method which lacks the flag `virtual` with respect to inheritance (hiding and overriding)? I searched through [ECMA335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) but couldn't find an exact description of the expected behaviour.

For example, let's have the base class `A` and the subclass `B`.

1. If `A` contains a method `M` with the flag `virtual`, and `B` contains a method `M` without the flag `virtual`, will `B.M` hide `A.M` or will it override it?
2. If `A` contains a method `M` with the flag `virtual`, and `B` contains a method `M` with `.override A.M`, but without the flag `virtual`, is the `virtual` implied, is `B.M` "virtual" only here (but, say, `B.M` can't be overriden in subclasses of `B`) or is this construction simply illegal (i.e. methods with `.override` *must* have the `virtual` flag)?

I'd like to know which part(s) of the spec answers these questions, so I'll be able to answer similar questions on my own in the future (I did search through it a lot before asking here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The representation is described in §23.1.10 Flags for methods [MethodAttributes], as `VtableLayoutMask`. When the mask is applied to the attributes, the result will be either `ReuseSlot` or `NewSlot`. `ReuseSlot` corresponds to the `override` keyword in C#, and `NewSlot` corresponds to the lack of `override` keyword or a method explicitly marked with `new`.

Hiding and overriding are different concepts. For example, if a method `Foo` in class `X` overrides a method of the same name in `BaseX`, then `X.Foo` *also* hides `BaseX`.

Now for the specific 2 questions in the original post:

1. If the CIL definition is not marked `newslot`, then if a method `B.M` hides `A.M` then `B.M` will also override `A.M`. (Partition II, §10.3.1)
2. Partition II, §10.3.2 states the following (emphasis mine):

   > The remaining information specifies the **virtual method** that provides the implementation.

   Combined with §15.4.2.2, it's clear that the `.override` directive can only refer to a method which is explicitly marked `virtual`.